# Selenium python send_keys doesnt work (though textfield is found and clicked)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation

```
def login(self):
    implicitly_wait(30)
    login_button = self.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@href, '/m-einloggen.html?targetUrl=%2Fs-anzeige%3Agesuche%2Fheimarbeit%2Fk0')]")
    login_button.click() 
    login_button.click() 
    self.implicitly_wait(30)
    email_button = self.find_element(By.ID, "email")
    email_button.clear() 
    self.implicitly_wait(30)
    email_button.click()
    email_button.send_keys(const.mail)
```

[My error message:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocTBg.png)

I'm trying to write an eBay automation with python. But it doesn't seem to work to pass keys to the field where you enter your mail to login.
It seems to be working that the button with the email text field is clicked, due to the fact that the cursor is blinking in it. But the keys aren't passed. I already tried clearing the field and implicit wait, in case my internet connection is too slow. Also I'm using the latest chrome version `119.0.6045.160`.... so I really don't know what could cause the error.
The error output is in the png.

Comment: Can you provide the URL of the page?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: @Shawn The url of the start page is https://www.kleinanzeigen.de/s-anzeige:gesuche/heimarbeit/k0

Comment: possible reason might be when u trying to pass key the elements changed. you can store the elements in a list then try to pass key  and make sure  you are selecting the right elements and better to add some time sleep or wait until element clickable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Root cause of the issue:** Your below XPath expression is not accurate, it is locating 2 web elements.

```
//*[contains(@href, '/m-einloggen.html?targetUrl=%2Fs-anzeige%3Agesuche%2Fheimarbeit%2Fk0')]
```

**Solution:** Use the below XPath expression to locate log-in element which is more simpler and easy to read:

```
//span[text()='Alle akzeptieren']
```

**Refactored working code below with in-line explanation:**

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.kleinanzeigen.de/s-anzeige:gesuche/heimarbeit/k0")

# create wait object which wait for 15s based on the condition
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)

# Below line will click on Alle akzeptieren button
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Alle akzeptieren']"))).click()

# Below line will click on Einloggen button
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Einloggen']"))).click()

# Below line will send email into text box
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "email"))).send_keys("myemail@gmail.com")
time.sleep(20)
```

**Result:**

[image]

**UPDATE:**
Refer the below screenshot. You will notice your XPath expression finds 2 results. Both the elements are in the screenshot highlighted in yellow.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It works with the akzeptieren button, but know I have to fix the bypass of a puzzle slide captcha in order to see if it works with the mail textfield. To you by any chance know how to bypass such a slider captcha?

Comment: And could you explain how the xpath element is locating two web elements? When I clicked on inspect the correct box was hihglited.

Comment: @NataschaFritschle - Check my updated answer. Hope this helps you understand the issue. Please stick to one issue per question. It's not advisable to ask multiple queries in one post. About bypassing the captcha, I suggest ask a new question, this way wider audience will see your question.

Comment: thank you very much! Will keep in mind that finding elements with their href is not the best way, due to lack of uniqueness.